# Cheap vs. expensive reflow oven

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, reflow

I am trying to build my capacity to solder SMD onto two-sided boards. As far as I understand, for example from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269832/reflow-oven-vs-even-hot-plate) post, a reflow oven is better than a hotplate for reasons of uniformity in temperature and the heating method.

In terms of reflow ovens, what is the general difference between cheap ones like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C9WQ8D9P), or others found on Amazon and much more expensive ones like [this](https://www.manncorp.com/collections/benchtop-smt-reflow-ovens/products/batch-smt-reflow-oven-nitrogen-compatible-mc301n), a model from Manncorp for over $8k?

I am also interested to know if someone has had success soldering two-sided boards with SMD using a hotplate, and what model was used.

Comment: Not familiar with that Manncorp part, but the page says that it does forced convection for heating, not just IR like the cheap amazon parts.  Compared to heating up a big resistor until it glows, blowing hot air will give a more uniform temperature but is (presumably) much more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

IR ovens seem great in principle but create hotspots and are very inconsistent.  A hotplate will typically give better results than the ubiquitous drawer style Chinese Amazon oven linked above, mainly because the heat is more consistent.

In my experiments, I found that air movement is critical, and most convection ovens will give better results than an IR only oven.  I tried and gave up on a similar drawer oven as shown in the Amazon link.

The simplest way is to get a good hot air gun, and maybe a preheater to run underneath and just flow it by eye.

For best results on something cheap, I’d probably consider some aftermarket controller for a convection oven down this line https://whizoo.com/

I have these items on my bench hakko fr-830, quick 861dw

Comment: Isn't "a preheater to run underneath" really just another way of saying " a hotplate"?

Comment: No, I use a hakko air preheater which makes a huge difference when hand reflowing under a reflow gun, especially with lead free.

Answer (score 2):

For prototyping and using leaded solder I've found the ubiquitous and even cheaper T962 to be adequate when set to an unleaded profile and the board is raised off the plate a bit. I have not tried it with unleaded paste, but I suspect it would have to be set even higher to get all the paste to flow on a large board.

For double-sided, I just run it twice.

I have a multi-zone conveyorized oven that maintains a far more correct profile because the boards move through the zone, getting proper preheat and then a brief high temperature spike, but it's not worth firing it up for a board or two. It handles unleaded paste with ease.

Comment: could you give model information for the multi-zone conveyorized oven?

Comment: It’s made by Puhui in Shandong. I imported it.